# Twitter Cards Not Validating

Tags: html, twitter, seo, meta

I am trying to test out the twitter cards and can't figure them out. I coppied one of their examples and just changed target link so it would link to my site. I created this quick example website to test out: http://www.canvasmagazine.tk/index.htm/

When I go to twitter card validator, it keeps returning the same error.

ERROR: FetchError:exceeded 4.seconds to Portal.Pink-constructor-safecore while waiting for a response for the request, including retries (if applicable) (Card error)

So I took out the CSS which has custom fonts and background and would slow down the runtime. Yet I still received the same error. I also went back and forth changing the metadata from name to property and then combined this with the above and still no luck. Hopefully it is something obvious I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="twitter:creator" content="@Environmentnyou">
<meta property="twitter:domain" content="http://canvasmagazine.tk/index.htm">
<meta property="twitter:title" content="Canvas Magazine | ">
<meta property="twitter:description" content="test">
<meta property="twitter:image" content="http://canvasmagazine.tk/images/tile.jpg">
```

EDIT: I also tried close  "/>" each meta tag instead of ">", yet this made no difference.

EDIT2: SOLVED. Twitter has blocked my server.

Comment: Please post an answer to your question, rather than editing that the question is solved into the question itself. That way, people won't skip over potentially useful advice because they think this problem was never resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I am too getting this problem and we were not able to figure out the issue.  But i have found certain troubleshooting steps which might be helpful to you.

1. Check robots.txt and make sure that `user-agent: twitterbot` is allowed.  Sometimes, Twitter is blocked from reading the metadata by this file.
2. Check that the IP Addresses of twitter server is not blocked by your host.  These are the IP Address used by twitter:

   > 199.59.148.209
   >   199.59.148.210
   >   199.59.148.211
   >   199.16.156.124
   >   199.16.156.125
   >   199.16.156.126

   (Source: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/troubleshooting)

   Also, Twitter’s ASNUM is AS13414.
3. Your Apache .htaccess file is denying requests.You can check this by opening your .htaccess file and looking for something like the following:

   deny from 199.59.149.*

Follow above mentioned troubleshooting steps and let us know if works for you!

Thanks,

Rakesh Solanki